# stacked bar graph with java and jasperSoft studio plugin in eclipse

Tags: java, charts, jasper-reports, bar-chart

How do i make a dynamic staked bar graph using jaspersoft. Currently the value column is not accepting list of values but instead it requires an integer. i am expecting the graph to loop through the list that i pass.

[image: jasper report design]

```
public class TeamPerformance {
    public List<TeamData> getReport(String reportId) {
        List<ContractionsPartogramData> result = new ArrayList<>();
        ContractionsPartogramData data = new ContractionsPartogramData();

        List<String> cat = new ArrayList<>();
        cat.add("11:00");
        cat.add("12:00");
        cat.add("13:00");

        List<Integer> teamOneScore = new ArrayList<>();
        teamOneScore.add(1);
        teamOneScore.add(11);
        teamOneScore.add(13);

        List<Integer> teamTwo = new ArrayList<>();
        teamTwo.add(4);
        teamTwo.add(14);
        teamTwo.add(5);

        data.setTeamOne(teamOneScore);
        data.setTeamTwo(teamTwo);
        data.setTeamOneSeries("Team One");
        data.setTeamTwoSeries("Team Two");
        data.setCategories(cat);

        result.add(data);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The *jrxml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="mbp_baby" pageWidth="1684" pageHeight="1190" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="1150" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="8f9fcfe4-de3f-44f2-a894-dd075a99d88e">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <subDataset name="BabyVisitsDataset" uuid="397116d3-884b-412b-aac0-f71201d3be28">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    </subDataset>
    <detail>
        <band height="343" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="79" y="59" width="99" height="20" uuid="af169a41-c5d0-49b5-87fb-b820c543167f"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                    <paragraph leftIndent="5"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Teams]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <stackedBarChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement x="43" y="78" width="200" height="200" uuid="ff603b1a-74f7-4c48-95a3-bbd94f9a2811"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{teamOne}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{categoryArray}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{arrayTeamOneValues}]]></valueExpression>
                        <labelExpression><![CDATA[]]></labelExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{teamTwo}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{categoryArray}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{arrayTeamOneValues}]]></valueExpression>
                        <labelExpression><![CDATA[]]></labelExpression>
                    </categorySeries>

                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </barPlot>
            </stackedBarChart>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Error stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
at net.sf.jasperreports.charts.fill.JRFillCategorySeries.evaluate(JRFillCategorySeries.java:141)
at net.sf.jasperreports.charts.fill.JRFillCategoryDataset.customEvaluate(JRFillCategoryDataset.java:110)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementDataset.evaluate(JRFillElementDataset.java:160)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.calculateVariables(JRCalculator.java:187)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:735)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:255)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:115)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:580)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:414)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:736)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.java:59)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.run(AbstractThreadSubreportRunner.java:221)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured it out why the chart was not able to plot. The structure of the data i was sending was in wrong format it was expecting.
I created a list which consist of three parameters namely values, category, and series and everything worked perfect. Lastly i added another dataset to contain the actual field names from the created list and attached it to the jrxml chart dataset.